# Inserting the value in Collection schema in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, database-design, database

I have the three data frame and I want to select the subset of each data frame based from the specific value in the column.

`data1 = pd.read_csv('path_of_the_file', sep=",")
data2 = pd.read_csv('path_of_the_file', sep=",")
data3 = pd.read_csv('path_of_the_file', sep=",")`

there is variable named "MAP" in all the data frame's . I want to create subset from all of the data frame like:
`From data1 
val1 val2 val3 MAP
12   78    45   101010101
13   71    76   101010101`

`From data2
val4 val5 val6 MAP
12   7190  89  101010101
13   2353  78  101010101
12    0    65  101010101`

`From data3
val7  val8  val9  MAP
1      78    0    101010101`

I want to insert this values of each row all together  in my mongo db Scheme.
This is what i have tried
`

```
uniqueVar_detail = data2.MAP.unique()
for i in range(0,len(uniqueVar_detail)):
    data1= data1[data1['MAP'] == uniqueVar_detail[i]]
    data2 = data2[data2['MAP'] == uniqueVar_detail[i]]
    data3 = data3[data3['MAP'] == uniqueVar_detail[i]]
    db.EVR.insert_one({"MAP_MESSAGE_ID":str(data1.MAP),
                       "data1" : [{
                         "val1":str (data1.val1),
                          "val2":str(data1.val2,
                          "val3" :str (data1.val3)
                        }],
                         "data2":[{
                          "val4" : str(data2.val4),
                           "val5": str(data2.val5),
                           "val6": str(data2.val6)
                            }],
                         "data3" :[{
                          "val7" : str(data3.val7),
                          "val8" : str(data3.val8),
                          "val9" : str(data3.val9)
                        }]
                       })
```

`

While Inserting I am also inserting the index of row. Like inserting in  "MAP" variable `960   101010101` , 960 is also inserted.
Any suggestion or some changes I need to do with the code?